# Calling C++ and ASM codes directly from Android Java

Tags: java, c++, c, assembly, jnienv

On JNI coding time, local `JNIEXPORT` functions showing for JNI beginners. If running C codes in C++ files from Android Java project is possible then are C and Assembly functions applicable in their syntax files?

You can explore [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) application for this question. Can you tell *.so libraries translated directly Assembly scripts?

Code type expanding.

Comment: If this is your question, neither JNI nor FFM cares about how the *binary* shared library was made. It could have been C, C++, Assembly, Rust, Go, or anything else. As long as it conforms to the ABI you can load and use it.

Comment: Please try to be clear in your questions. It seems that English may not be your main language which is understandable but it is very difficult to make sense of your comment.

Comment: The question revised.

Comment: ...Successful solution. But is not including information about directly reactions of C++-Java. As a sample, can we subjected C codes from externs "C" {} blocks of C++ files?